# Form that sends html template to email

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

The form contents are sent to my email but HTML and CSS code is not recognised on the email. Only plain text is outputted.

**Below is my controller**

```
public function registration() {

    $email = $this->input->post('email');
    $domain = $this->input->post('domain_name');
    $passw = $this->input->post('passw');
    $name = $this->input->post('name');
    $skype = $this->input->post('skype');
    //  $package = $this->input->post('package');

    $config = Array(
        'protocol' => 'smtp',
        'smtp_host' => 'xxxx.com',
        'smtp_port' => 25,
        'smtp_user' => 'xxx@xxxxxx.com',
        'smtp_pass' => 'xxxxx',
        'mailtype' => 'html',
        'charset' => 'iso-8859-1'
    );

    $this->load->library('email', $config);
    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
    $this->email->from('xxx@xxxxxx.com', 'welcome');
    $this->email->to('xxxxx@xxxxxxxx.com');

    $this->email->subject('registration');

    $body = $this->load->view('dns/template', TRUE);


    $this->email->message($body, TRUE);

    $this->email->send();

    $data['message'] = 'Submitted Sucessfullly';
    $data['emails'] = $this->Dns_model->emails($domain);

    $this->load->view('dns/sucessful', $data);
}
```

Below is my view saved as template.php

**My view (template)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<html> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<title>Registration</title>
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url()?>/assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url()?>/assets/css/bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url()?>/assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url()?>/assets/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url()?>/assets/css/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url()?>/assets/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url()?>/assets/css/AdminLTE.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url()?>/assets/css/sl-slide.css">

    <script src="<?php echo base_url()?>/assets/js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2-respond-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>

    <!-- Le fav and touch icons -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo base_url()?>/images/ico/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="<?php echo base_url()?>/images/ico/apple-touch-icon-144-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="<?php echo base_url()?>/images/ico/apple-touch-icon-114-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="i<?php echo base_url()?>/mages/ico/apple-touch-icon-72-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="<?php echo base_url()?>/images/ico/apple-touch-icon-57-precomposed.png">

 </head>

<body id="con"  onLoad="generate();">
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<div class="container">
<section class="main-info">
<br>
<section id="recent-works3">

<section id="pricing-table">


    <div class="row-fluid center clearfix">



        <div class="span3">

        </div>



        <div class="span6">
 <ul class="plan plan3">
                    <li class="plan-name">             
                        <span class="lead3">Emails to be setup</span>
                    </li>
  </ul>
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
     <th>Email</th>
     <th>Password</th>
     </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
     <tr class="info">
     <td>info@test.com</td>
     <td>terfwws6w</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    <ul class="plan plan3">
      <li class="plan-action">
       <a href="http://www.xxxxxx.com" class="btn btn-transparent">Registration website</a>
         </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="span3">


        </div>
    </div>
</section>
</section>
</section>
</div>
</div>                       
 <script src="<?php echo base_url()?>/assets/js/vendor/jquery-1.9.1.min.js">     </script>
 <script src="<?php echo base_url()?>/assets/js/vendor/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script src="<?php echo base_url()?>/assets/js/main.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url()?>/assets/js/jquery.ba-cond.min.js"></script>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: Where is the email template?

Comment: Try html email https://css-tricks.com/sending-nice-html-email-with-php/

Comment: what is error or output ??

Comment: Thank you. @xpuc7o i have updated and added my template ,@ Abdulla am not getting any error, Just plain text is appearing, no css on email

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are not using Parser library for email template, so bellow is my Answer by considering the above Condition.

1. You have problem with your template, means the Html code you wrote there, they have mismatched tag or some tag used in Wrong place. So you have to check that first.
2. If still you are not able to find out the problem then you just create a template using bellow code and You will see that the mail not more in normal text..

   Nice, You nailed it...

> NOTE: Don't use  or  etc tag and Also Use `<table>` instead of `<div>`

Comment: Try to make the template with inline css and all code should goes inside table tag.